# How do I set a value based on the contents of different columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

I don't usually use excel so I need some help. I basically want to create a column called HasSomething, which populates the cells in those column with 1 if Column1 OR Column2 OR Column3 has any value in it, or 0 if there's nothing in all three. Any tips on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [COUNTA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/counta-HP005209027.aspx) function. It counts the number of cells that are not empty:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:C1),1,0)
```

or another option for you:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:C1)<3,1,0)
```

Comment: That's giving me 1 for all cases, even if Column1, Column2, and Column3 are empty.

Comment: are you sure that they are actually empty (even without formulas that returns empty string)? check also spaces in cells

Comment: Hmm, they indeed are empty, but your formula shows 1 until I click Column1, Column2, and Column3, after which it changes to a 0. Weird. Why is this happening and how can I make it apply throughout? I have over 20,000 rows and I'm certainly not going to click on 60,000 cells to get it done :P

Comment: Check your calculation mode. It seems that you have manual calculation mode. Change it to automatic. See this screen for details: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgPX.png. Also you can try `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:C1)<3,1,0)`.

Comment: My calculation mode was already in Automatic. However, the second formula that you posted seems to work like a charm! Thanks :)